# Remove shorter items in array that are already present

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to remove items from array that are present already in longer items.
For Example if I have two items 'Knowledge base' and 'base' I want to remove 'base', if I have knowledge management multiple times I want to leave all items unless there is an item that contain those two words but it's longer for example 'knowledge management book'.

It's easy to sort items by length but I'm not sure how to check for example if 'base' is already present in longer term('Knowledge base')

So in the example below desired solution would be:

```
const items = ['Knowledge base', 'knowledge management', 'knowledge management']
```

```js
const items = ['Knowledge base', 'base', 'management', 'knowledge management', 'Knowledge', 'knowledge', 'knowledge management']

const newItems = items.sort((a,b) => b.length - a.length)

console.log(newItems)
```

Comment: Why `'knowledge management'` is present twice in the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Array.filter()` along with `Array.some()` to filter any items that are included in other items.

```js
const items = ['Knowledge base', 'base', 'management', 'knowledge management', 'Knowledge', 'knowledge', 'knowledge management'];

const result = items.filter(item => !items.some(it => it !== item && it.includes(item)));

console.log('Result:', result);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, and way better then my idea with a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Filter by some and verify by includes methods

```js
const items = ['Knowledge base', 'base', 'management', 'knowledge management', 'Knowledge', 'knowledge', 'knowledge management'];

const newItems = items.filter((item) => {
      return !items.some((iChecker) => {
           return iChecker !== item && iChecker.includes(item)
         }
      ) 
  }
);

console.log( { newItems } );
```